# color for selected text

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

```
environment: visual studio 2008
```

You know in visual studio 2008 in the editor? You can double-click a word and it will highlight all instances of that word. well, the highlight is a very light pink background that I can't hardly see. is there a way to change that to a darker color?

It's not the word that I double-click on it's the other matching words of what I double-click, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors->

Try changing the color for "Inactive Selected Text"

If that's not it, you can arrow down through the items until you see the color you want to change.